# JavaScript: lifetime of an image declared inside a function with a load listener attached

Tags: javascript

I need to create a temporary image, wait for it to load extract dataURL from it and remove it from memory, here is my current code:

```js
const get = id => document.getElementById(id);

const handler = evt => {
    const icon = new Image();
  icon.addEventListener('load', evt => { 
    // image -> canvas -> dataURL
    console.log('boom');
    evt.target.removeEventListener('load', handler);
  });
  icon.src = src;
};

get('btn').addEventListener('click', handler);

const src='https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200';
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tfoller/Lg6we5cf/12/

It looks like the image lifetime is longer than the handler function because of the listener attached, so I remove the listener after processing, is that the correct way to make sure the image will be picked up by GC?

EDIT following Teemu comments:

```js
const get = id => document.getElementById(id);

const handler = evt => {
    const icon = new Image();
  icon.addEventListener('load', function loaded(evt) { 
    // image -> canvas -> dataURL
    console.log('boom');
    evt.target.removeEventListener('load', loaded);
  });
  icon.src = src;
};

get('btn').addEventListener('click', handler);

const src='https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200';
```

Comment: FYI: There are [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) which you can use instead of JSFiddle. This way users don't have to go to an external site.

Comment: Nope, `handler` is attached to the button, not to image, `removeEventListener` won't find a load event attached to `handler` function. Switch the arrow function to named function, and use its name to remove the event listener from the image.

Comment: `icon.addEventListener('load', function loaded (evt) {...});`.

Comment: @Teemu why would `evt.target` inside the load callback not work? It points to the image only rihgt

Comment: Yes, `loaded` is the name the function knows inside itself, that's what you're goint to use when removing the listener. @TusharShahi `evt.target` inside the load listener refers to the image, `handler` function was never attached to the image, it was attached to the button.

Comment: Oh yes. I didn't see the we are trying to remove `handler`.